# Is it possible to add descriptions to custom Google Spreadsheets commands?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

And on a side note, since I have to type in some question body and title explains it all, can I make only some of the JavaScript functions in my script usable as custom commands?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can. Here is a simple example:

```
/**
 * A custom function that converts meters to miles.
 *
 * @param {Number} meters The distance in meters.
 * @return {Number} The distance in miles.
 * @customFunction
 */
function metersToMiles(meters) {
  if (typeof meters != 'number') {
    return null;
  }
  return meters / 1000 * 0.621371;
}
```

So you write documentation for this as simple **JSDoc**, but then you add `@customFunction` annotation in it. Documentation for this function becomes visible in the editor.

Comment: Oh my, can't believe I missed your answer somehow. Big thanks, accepted it! :)